# Meteor(React) : GPS based tracking for checkout

Tags: gps, tracking, meteor-react

Created a application(iOS) using Meteor-react framework for car rental parking. I wants to track the drivers mobile using GPS. So that I can detect his checkout status. I need to calculate distance between parking space and drivers location once check-in so that I can send push messages to driver whether he is about to check-out. Before going for a actual development for GPS based checkout need a suggestion is it really possible? What will be the pron and cons?

Right-now I am going through npm package "gps-tracking" which is a GPS listener.

Below code I have added in /server/gps.js

```
var gps = require("gps-tracking");
var options = {
'debug'                 : true, //We don't want to debug info 
 automatically. We are going to log everything manually so you can 
 check what happens everywhere
'port'                  : 8000,
'device_adapter'        : "TK103"
}

var server = gps.server(options,function(device,connection){
console.log(options);
console.log(device);
console.log(connection);
device.on("connected",function(data){
    console.log("I'm a new device connected");
    return data;

});
device.on("login_request",function(device_id,msg_parts){

    console.log('Hey! I want to start transmiting my position. Please accept me. My name is '+device_id);

    this.login_authorized(true); 

    console.log("Ok, "+device_id+", you're accepted!");

});
device.on("ping",function(data){
    //this = device
    console.log("I'm here: "+data.latitude+", "+data.longitude+" ("+this.getUID()+")");

    //Look what informations the device sends to you (maybe velocity, gas level, etc)
    //console.log(data);
    return data;

});
device.on("alarm",function(alarm_code,alarm_data,msg_data){
    console.log("Help! Something happend: "+alarm_code+" 
("+alarm_data.msg+")");
}); 
//Also, you can listen on the native connection object
connection.on('data',function(data){
    //echo raw data package
    //console.log(data.toString()); 
})
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you don't mind sharing, it will be quite interesting to hear the approach opted by you. Since it was posted long back I assume you already figured this out.